# Regex and csv from google link in Windows

Tags: python, regex

I am beginner, so excuse me if this is not a good question. i am trying to use regex to extract coordinate from a list of google map links in csv file (under a column named "site" , then i will create csv file with the first column in "link_loc.csv" and the 2 column with the new coordinates long and lat.

the link in "link_loc.csv" look like

"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=31.99970589000%2C35.08542317&z=17&hl=en"

and i want to extract 31.99970589000 and this 35.08542317

i used the following code but i had error

can you help

```
import re
```

out = open("coordinates.csv", "w")

with open ("link_loc.csv") as file:
    for row in file:
        if column== "site":

```
        pattern = r"(\d+[.]\d+)*%2C(\d+[.]\d+)"
        result = re.search(pattern, row)
        out.write(result[1],result[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse urls, I recommend the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module instead of regexes (though you could do it that way too). Here's an example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

s = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=31.99970589000%2C35.08542317&z=17&hl=en'
parsed = urlparse(s)
queries = parse_qs(parsed.query)
coordinates = queries['q'][0].split(',')

print(parsed)
print(queries)
print(coordinates)
```

Output:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='maps.google.com', path='/maps', params='', query='q=31.99970589000%2C35.08542317&z=17&hl=en', fragment='')
{'q': ['31.99970589000,35.08542317'], 'z': ['17'], 'hl': ['en']}
['31.99970589000', '35.08542317']
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but what i have hundreds lines (links), what  can i do to iterate through them ?

Comment: This method will work fine with hundreds or thousands of links. First, wrap my code in a function that accepts a url and returns the coordinates. Then apply it to a list in one expression using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). For example: `coordinates = [extract_coordinates(url) for url in urls]`

Comment: Thank you , i put in def and it worked , but my problem from the beginning is to iterate through links listed in csv file.

from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def get_cor (link):
    parsed = urlparse(s)
    queries = parse_qs(parsed.query)
    coordinates = queries['q'][0].split(',')
    return coordinates

print(get_cor('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=31.99970589000%2C35.08542317&z=17&hl=en'))

Comment: Probably the easiest way to iterate over a csv file is to load it in a pandas dataframe with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). For example: `import pandas as pd`, `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`, `urls = df['site'].tolist()`